# Mysql selection from more than one table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

```
SELECT * FROM dog WHERE (SELECT calluser FROM jos_users WHERE `user_id`='".$cid."')=Subcode
```

`$cid` is the identifier in `jos_users`, which tells us which users we're fetching data about

The data I want to fetch is within "dog", and calluser is the identifier between the two (which tells us who's dogs are who's)

I need to be able to call only the dogs relevant to the user in question, but it also has to be performed in one query. Can anyone help? Much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look up joins and inner joins in the mysql manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right (and the id column in the dog-table links to the calluser column in the jos_user-table) the query should be

```
SELECT d.* FROM dog AS d JOIN jos_user AS u ON d.id = u.calluser WHERE u.user_id = '$cid'
```

If not please explain your data structure in more detail (maybee small ER diagram).

Comment: You have an error on your SQL right here: `u.user_id = $cid`. **Always surround injected vars with single quotes.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use joins.
Read this tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Your query should look something like this:

```
$cid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cid']);
$query = "SELECT d.* FROM dog d
INNER JOIN jos_users ju ON (d.user_id = ju.id) 
WHERE ju.id = '$cid' ";
```